# Disable auto diff on file open

Tags: visual-studio

I did something dumb. Somehow I changed something in Visual Studio 2019 such that whenever I open any file in the Solution Explorer, it shows me a diff between my branch and the source branch. Does anyone know how to fix this so it just shows my file? I have absolutely no idea how I did this and google hasn't been much help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a button next to the find in files button that diffs everything. It's the button circled in red
[image]